# TCP Socket communication between iOS app and Android app

Tags: sockets

iOS app on iPhone and Android app on Samsung Galaxy S3 needs to communicate each other on Wifi network.

I'm using `CocoaAsyncSocket` library in iOS app and `java.net.Socket` in Android app.

==iOS app part==

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket
{
    [clientSocketList addObject:newSocket];

    NSMutableDictionary *newClientInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [newClientInfo setObject:@"0" forKey:@"status"];

    [clientInfoList addObject:newClientInfo];

    [newSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
- (void) writeData:(NSData*)data to:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock {
    NSMutableData *dataWithLine = [data mutableCopy];
    [dataWithLine appendData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData]];

    [sock writeData:dataWithLine withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
```

==Android part==

```
public boolean connectServer() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(SOMEIP, SOMEPORT);

        binaryInput = socket.getInputStream();
        this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(binaryInput));
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(status != STATUS_STOPPED) {
                try {
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    //Doing stuff
                } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    out.println(message);
}
```

---

In the above code, iOS app is a server and Android app is a client.

What I'm intending to do in above code is

- Android app sends message and iOS app receives it. Each message is identified by new line character. Android app sends message by `println` method and iOS app receives message until receiving CRLF(new line) character.
- iOS app sends message and Android app receives it. Each message is identified by new line character. iOS app sends message by attaching CRLF in the end and Android app receives message by `readline` method.

---

Problem is when android app sends message, iOS app's didReceiveData delegate is not called. One thing is clear that iOS app socket can't find the CRLF character in the streaming.

I tried to send message from Android app by attaching CRLF bytes ([0x0d,0x0a]) after the real data, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In Java/Android, `PrintWriter.println()` writes an OS-specific line break.  `CRLF` is the Windows line break.  On Android, it uses `LF` instead.  If the iOS reader only expects `CRLF` and does not allow `LF`, it will never be triggered.

To force CRLF, use `PrintWriter.print()` instead:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    out.print(message + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.The actual solution was `out.flush()`. Solved it!